# How to create scrollable stack view with multiple stack views in swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I am trying to create a scrollable stack view.
e.g Its hierarchy would be like this

```
-ScrollView
--StackView 
---StackView1
---StackView2
---StackView3
.....
---StackView12
```

[image]

**StackView1,StackView2, ...., StackView12** will have dynamic height and same width as of OuterMost Scroll View.

And OuterMost StackView also have same width as of OuterMost Scroll View.

I have set properties of OuterMost StackView as bellow:

```
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: FillEqually
Spacing: 15
```

All the sub StackViews (StackView1,StackView2, ...., StackView12) doing well.

I have also added this in my swift code

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    OutMostScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: OutMostStackView.frame.width, height: OutMostStackView.frame.height)
}
```

But I am unable to scroll in the OuterMost StackView.Please anybody guide me the true way to achieve this.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the height of 250 in the height parameter of  **OutMostScrollView** and the problem solved. Now It scrolls to the end.

```
OutMostScrollView.contentSize.height = OutMostStackView.frame.height+250
```

what I get from this is I think there may be some hidden height other than `OutMostStackView.frame.height` which is consumed by the view controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

I've made an example of scroll in stack view.

It's simple and complete, don't need story board (programmatically).

You can see it in gist below:

[Scroll stackView in Swift](https://gist.github.com/moraei/08f1c1841f7bb73bb5c9e89ac428e027)